# Associate a QWidget with an QSetting value?

Tags: qt, qt4, qsettings

I'm kinda tired to do

```
QSettings::beginGroup ("Some group");
QSettings::setValue ("Some fields", ui->lineEdit->text());
```

I mean, if I could just specify that the `text` property of `ui->lineEdit` should be associated with the "Some group/Some fields" setting, I could save all these lines. **Also the load settings part.**

So I'm wondering if there's some easy framework that directly associate the widget property with some QSettings field?

If not, what's the recommend way to implement it?

Comment: I took the liberty of bumping this question by bolding a part I would like to know.